# Transparent, borderless text input

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the border around an `<input type="text">` and make its background transparent?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try this:

```css
border: none;
border-color: transparent;
```

Answer (score 22):

```
border: none transparent;
outline: none;
```

This will not only remove the border around the input field but also the orange highlight when the input is in focus.

Comment: +1 outline:none makes the border disappear even when the input is focused. Otherwise, border:none is not enough.

Answer (score 18):

Like this:

```css
input {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never:

```
input {border-style:none;}
```

Comment: Better late than never, yes, but this just duplicates two existing answers (`border: none;` is shorthand for `border-style: none;`).

Comment: @minitech Isn't border shorthand for border-width, border-style, and border-color?

Comment: Yes, and `border: none;` sets `border-style: none;`.